# Count of DataExtension Rows from API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel-sdk

Is there a way to get the count of data-extension rows without pulling and counting them? (from API)

I can't find a size property of the data-extension, but I assume this functionality is somehow possible, as the ET Dashboard does have the size's of all there data-extensions.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the solution with an undocumented REST endpoint - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/321889/72249

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  Best work-around I've seen is to create a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) that counts the rows of the Data Extension on some interval.  Then you can simply retrieve the resulting data via API ([DataExtensionObject](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextensionobject/)).

EDIT:

An alternate method is [**outlined here**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/220831/5202), if you have Cloud Pages enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential workaround would be to use the Action of GetMaxCount with the Perform method.  This would require that an EmailSendDefinition exist in the account where the data extension of interest is the target.  This would only be good if you wanted a quick total right before sending, if you wanted to see a large list of DEs with their counts then this would not be a very performant option.

https://help.exacttarget.com/fi/technical_library/web_service_guide/methods/perform/